# Substring of a specific occurence

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have a column as varchar2 datatype, the data in it is in format:

```
100323.3819823.222
100.323123.443422
1001010100.233888
LOL12333.DDD33.44
```

I need to remove the whole part after the first occurrence of '.'

In the end it should look like this:

```
100323
100
1001010100
LOL12333
```

I cant seem to find the exact substring expression due to the fact that there is not  any fix length of the first part.

Comment: Do you know about Oracle's [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) ?

Comment: Add one row without any `.`, and one row with only an `.` etc, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name,'^[^.]*') FROM table
```

The other way is to combine `SUBSTR` with `INSTR`, which is a bit faster, but will result in `NULL` if the data doesn't contain a dot, so you'll have to add a switch if needed:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column_name, 1, INSTR(column_name,'.') - 1) FROM table
```

Comment: with the added observation that the SUBSTR + INSTR solution will be quite a bit faster, if that is important.

Answer (score 1):

For oracle you can try this:

```
select substr (i,1,Instr(i,'.',i)-1) from Table name.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with th `@` symbol in Oracle SQL. Are you sure your solution works with Oracle database?

Comment: You have to replace @t with your table name. I am not sure if charindex is available in Oracle.

Comment: Oracle has no CHARINDEX function.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `CHARINDEX` only exists in _SQL Server_. For your information, Oracle has `INSTR` function. Did you not see the "oracle" tag on this question?